# How do I listen for updates to specific precached resources?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have a bunch of files in my PWA precache managed by Workbox. How would I listen for updates to these precached files?

**Background:** Safari seems to hold on to outdated copies of CSS files after `window.location.reload()`, so if an update to my app includes updates to CSS I would like to be able to tell the user to [force-close](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201330) and restart the app.

I have tried adding the `BroadcastUpdate` plugin:

```
workbox.precaching.addPlugins([
    new workbox.broadcastUpdate.BroadcastUpdatePlugin(),
]);
```

After doing this I expected messages to be sent if a new service worker version brought new versions of precached files with it. I was then going to check the message event and if the URL ended with `.css` I could ask the user to force-close at the relevant moment.

However, no messages are sent when I update the app (update the precache manifest using [injectManifest](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/precache-files/workbox-build) and call [reg.update()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update)).

I know that the message listener code is working. I use it in other places. But the `BroadcastUpdatePlugin` does not seem to send any messages when precached files change.

What's wrong here? Am I just expecting the wrong thing from `BroadcastUpdatePlugin`? Is it not supposed to be used with precaching? If so does anyone have any other ideas about how I can simply listen for updates to precached resources?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Solution is to add a custom plugin to the precache:

```js
const precacheUpdatePlugin = {
    cacheDidUpdate: async ({request, response, event}) => {
        if (/^.*\.css.*$/.test(request.url)) {
            self.sendMessageToAllClients('CSS_UPDATE_DETECTED');
        }
    }
}
workbox.precaching.addPlugins([
    precacheUpdatePlugin,
]);
```

No idea what's going on in the Workbox `BroadcastUpdatePlugin` but this works.